# Ansible collection not detected when running playbook on AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, netapp

I use modules from the collection `netapp.ontap` in my ansible playbook which works perfectly fine when run using `ansible-playbook` command.
However, when run from `AWX`, it fails to detect the collection and immediately throws an errors that it cannot detect the ansible module/collection.
I even tried to re-install the collection from the playbook itself but with no luck.

The ansible collection is confirmed to be installed as it already works fine when run outside AWX.

The host is running ansible 2.10.4.

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
 
  collections:
  - netapp.ontap

  tasks: 
   
  - name: Install Netapp Collection from Ansible Galaxy
    shell: ansible-galaxy collection install netapp.ontap


  - name: Run Task
    import_tasks: tasks/hil.yml
```

Task:

```
- name: 'Gather SVMs'
  netapp.ontap.na_ontap_info:
    state: info
    hostname: "{{ netapp_hostname }}"  
    username: "{{ netapp_username }}"
    password: "{{ netapp_hv_password }}"
    gather_subset:
    - vserver_info
```

Error from AWX:

```
SSH password: 
Vault password: 
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'netapp.ontap.na_ontap_info'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_421_gey54bdw/project/tasks/hil.yml': line 6, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
- name: 'Gather SVMs'
  ^ here
This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote. For instance:
    when: "ok" in result.stdout
Could be written as:
   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'
Or equivalently:
   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

Update:
I created a collections/requirements.yml file, with the below details but now AWX fails the task itself.

collections/requirements.yml

```yaml
collections:
   name: https://github.com/ansible-collections/netapp.git
   type: git
```

Error:

```
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awx/main/tasks.py", 
line 1279, in run self.pre_run_hook(self.instance, private_data_dir) File 
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awx/main/tasks.py", 
line 1862, in pre_run_hook sync_task.run(local_project_sync.id) File 
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awx/main/tasks.py", 
line 698, in _wrapped return f(self, *args, **kwargs) File 
"/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awx/main/tasks.py", 
line 1444, in run raise AwxTaskError.TaskError(self.instance, rc) 
Exception: project_update 435 (failed) encountered an error (rc=2), please 
see task stdout for details.
```

Comment: This is not the way to install collections in AWX. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html#collections-support

Comment: Moreover, it would not work either outside of awx: the full playbook is parsed at start and ansible will fire an error if it does not recognize a module. So you will never get a chance to play your install task as written above.

Comment: The playbook runs outside AWX, It's been working for quite some time now. Outside AWX, ansible detects the collection with no issues. I followed the link you mentioned above but it's not working either (check the edited part of the question)

Comment: The playbook runs outside of awx because as mentionned, you already installed the collection in your other environment. Regarding the new try and your new error, there is a typo in your requirement file => `colelctions` => `collections`

Comment: thanks for noticing that! unfortunately, it still throws the same error after fixing the typo.

Comment: What do you get in awx logs ?